# How to open any URL in "Location" or "Body" of Google Calendar in new tab without any Redirection Notice or error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am developing a Chrome Extension. In this, my task is to populate **Location** with some URL and **Body** of Google Calendar with message containing some URL.

I have found that, If I filled **LOCATION** with URL starting of "https://". It redirects me to another window tab showing **REDIRECTION NOTICE ERROR**.
[image]

And, I filled **LOCATION** with URL starting of "www". It redirects me to another window tab and opens Google Map.
[image]

Also, **Body** of Google Calendar with message containing some URL ,URL opens into another tab but with redirection message.
[image]

My worry is for this redirection. How can I remove or avoid this redirection errors and screen?

Looking forward for solution.
Thanks!!

Comment: Am also facing similar problem.

Comment: Hi there @NehaSoni and @KanakSony! The first picture depicts a redirection notice consent request to the user. That is a security measure that shouldn't be bypassed. To prevent missing any step, could you please share the code that you are using to provoke the link in Maps behaviour?

Comment: Hi Jacques-Guzel Heron, thanks for response. My task is just to populate custom URL into LOCATION section of Google Calendar. Even I have found this behavior when I manually write URL into LOCATION.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your new comments I have a better understanding of your issue. First of all, you should use the *location* property for the physical address where the event will take place, as is described in the [`Event`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) resource.

On the other hand, if you want to share a link in the event, you are correct doing it in the `description` property. During some milliseconds you will get a redirecting alert as your third pic, but that is something natural and unavoidable because you are really redirecting people from Calendar to external places.